# JComboBox not populating from Hashtable and ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, hashtable, jcombobox

I'm creating a Fruit and Vedg application that allows users to pick from drop down boxes.   My JComboBox *subComboBox* will populate if I use an String[] rather than ArrayList.  Any thoughts or documents I could view?  With the code below the *subComboBox* is empty.

```
public class FruitAndVedg extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
private JComboBox mainComboBox;
private JComboBox subComboBox;
private ArrayList item;
private Hashtable<ArrayList<Object>, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<>();

public FruitAndVedg() {
    item = new ArrayList();
    item.add("Select Item");
    item.add("Fruit");
    item.add("Vedg");

    mainComboBox = new JComboBox(item.toArray());
    mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
    mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);

    subComboBox = new JComboBox();
    subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX");

    getContentPane().add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    String[] subItems1 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Plum"};
    subItems.put(item, subItems1);

    String[] subItems2 = {"Select Vedg", "Carrot", "Peas"};
    subItems.put(item, subItems2);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    Object o = subItems.get(item);
    if (o == null) {
        subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
    } else {
        subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
    }
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        if (ie.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
            if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            }
        }
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new FruitAndVedg();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

No error messages reported.

Comment: Hashtable<ArrayList<Object>, Object>, have to change this paramaters to Hashtable<Object, Object> and to use (starting with) the same arrays type for all elemnts in HashTable, meaning  item = new ArrayList(); back to String[], because rest of alements are String[]

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to turn all the String[]'s to ArrayLists.

Comment: `item.add("Vedg");`  Side note:  The word 'vegetable' has no 'D'.  Don't include one for an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My JComboBox subComboBox will populate if I use an String[] rather than ArrayList.

The default ComboBoxModel doesn't support ArrayList.

You can use a Vector.

If you really want to use an ArrayList then you need to create a custom model. Or create a loop to add the items from the ArrayList to the model one at a time. Creating a custom model isn't that hard, just copy the code for the DefaultComboBoxModel and change the code to use a List instead of a Vector.